# git / gerrit prevent develop branch to be merged into stable / testing branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, gerrit

Using Gerrit it is easy to accidentally merge unstable code from the develop branch into the stable branch:

`$ git checkout develop

$ commit

$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/stable`

In Gerrit it isn't very clear that the proposed change comes from the develop branch and is to be merged into the stable branch. Is there a way to prevent this merge from happening, either in git or in Gerrit?

**Update:**
For now we use a custom command to push to gerrit which finds the last branch in origin it was based on and only allow pushing to that branch.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527833/how-to-configure-git-to-avoid-accidental-git-push

Comment: The solution to that question prevents pushing at all. I'd like to push, but want to prevent develop (or any branch created from develop) to be pushed to refs/for/testing or refs/for/stable

Comment: So you have to make custom pre-receive hook for your remote repo

Comment: ...which is impossible with gerrit :'(

Comment: Your topic summary said "merged" but your example merely shows a push to gerrit, which doesn't merge until it's approved.  If you want to prevent the push, then your script seems the correct thing.  If you want to prevent the merge (in gerrit), then you can go to the Project / Access options and make sure there is not a Submitters allowed for  the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no options in software which would prevent You from making this kind of mistake.

There are, however, a few things You could do:

- train people, so they always check the branch name while performing a review
- set up a "pushed to correct branch" category (howto [here](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.1/access-control.html#category_makeoneup)) with options like +1 "Correct branch", 0 "No score", -1 "Incorrect branch", so the reviewer has to formally confirm that he checked the branch name
- set up a continuous integration tool to automatically review and score the aforementioned category ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) has a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) You could use)

Would You share the custom command You use to push to gerrit, please?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be something like this:

Segregate users

- Submitter group - All developers who you would be expecting to commit to 'develop' only and not in 'main'
- Integrator group - Privileged developers who can push and merge to 'main', create more branches if required.

In 'git' allow push access to members of 'Integrator group' (described above) only.

Disclaimer: I do not have Gerrit/Git admin role/configuration experience, so I honestly have no clue how 'git' will be able to pickup information about which group any user belongs to (IMHO this could still be manually achieved).

Answer (score 0):

You should setup specific access controls in Gerrit for your "develop" branch of that repo.

Setup like this:

```
Reference: refs/for/refs/heads/develop
Push: Allow: <group>
```

But **not** like this:

```
Reference: refs/for/refs/heads/*
Push: Allow: <group>
```

This way your `<group>` can only push for review on "refs/for/develop", not "refs/for/stable" or any other branch.