# How create a project-fork with git (no github fork!) and keep relation to original repository

Tags: git

I have a project A, which acts as a starting point for other projects. To start a new project B I simply clone A (changing the folder name to B):

```
git clone git@host:A B
```

And change the origin to B

```
git remote rename origin base-project
git remote add git@host:B
```

Now I have the project A's repository available as base-project (I do not like it beeing named upstream, because this could be confused with github forks) and I can work on project B as I like.

To later pull changes from A I do:

```
git pull base-project master
```

Is my way of doing it right or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good way to keep a reference to a template repo, while establishing a new origin repo (the one where you will push to).

What you can add is (see "[How to configure git to avoid accidental git push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817345/6309)"):

```
git config remote.base-project.receivepack /bin/false
```

That way, you are sure you won't be pushing to A (base-project) by mistake.